# Eclipse complains about "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am picking up an old project which has a lot of old dependencies.
I am using "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers".
After importing the source to Eclipse, Eclipse is complaining all my jsp files that

```
The superclass "jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path
```

In pom.xml, I see there is this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I went to google about the error and read a bit of javax vs jakarta history.
The thing is, because this is an old project that is still running on the server... can I stick with javax and not jakarta?

In Eclipse, under Project Facets, I have "Dynamic Web Module" checked and it is using Apache Tomcat v9.0 locally.
Under Server settings, I have "Tomcat v9.0 Server" at localhost for running this project.

Another thing I don't know if it has anything to do with setup of my Tomcat or project settings, which is that on pom.xml, I get an error about missing a lot of artifacts, like "jini:jsk-lib:jar",  "jini:reggie:jar", "jini:start:jar", etc...

Comment: You are likely using an older version of Eclipse. Upgrade. Also, Tomcat 9 is not a Jakarta EE server, it would still use `javax.servlet`.

Comment: I resolved similar problem by changing from Dynamic Web Project version 4 to Version 5.  This is done by selecting the version in Project/properties/ProjectFacets.  You should see Dynamic Web Version with a dropdown to select version number.  I'm using Tomcat version 10.1.4.  Under runtimes, in same window, I've got Apache Tomcat 10.1.4 selected. That runtime has the right jakarta servlet-api.jar contained in it.  If you want to stick with javax, you'll have to select an earlier runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can I stick with javax and not jakarta?

Yes, certainly you can stick with the `javax.` naming rather than migrating to the new `jakarta.` namespace. Eventually you’ll want to make the migration to benefit from new and improved technologies. But not necessary this year or next.

Read the [*Which version?*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) documentation page. You will see that versions 9.0.x and 10.0.x are functionally equivalent, developed in parallel. The only significant difference is that namespace change discussed above. So use Tomcat 9 if you choose to stick with `javax` naming.

You’ll need to get your codebase in order, to use only the `javax.` naming. Apparently you have some code that refers to the new `jakarta.` naming. Fix that. Check your `import` statements. Check any use of fully-qualified class names. Use your IDE’s search tools.

By the way… If using Tomcat 9, you can change that dependency on the Servlet API from 3.0.1 to the version 4.0.3 of the [Servlet specification](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.servlet). See that *Which version?* page linked above, as well as the https://Jakarta.EE site, to learn the appropriate versions of specs for JSPs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

just go to mavenrepository
and serach for java servlet api
then click on the version api
then scroll down copy the dependency  which looks like below

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

now past this in pom.xml in your project within dependency tag which is already present.
after this
right click on the project
and select maven
select update project
then check force update
then click ok
this will solve your error

Answer (score 0):

In order to run javax.servlet with JSP you need two dependencies.

First one is servlet api,

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Second one is JSP api,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Note: `javax.servlet.jsp-api` also include the dependency to `javax.servlet-api`, so you do not need it explicitly in your project.

This means that, `javax.servlet-api` is mendatory for JSP to work.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to specify the apache 10 server while creating your project in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I also tried solving by using all the above but the problem was that I had not added the Tomcat server on my runtime.

You can foolow this [blog](https://www.positioniseverything.net/the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build-path/) which actually worked for me:

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35444647)